# Unable to connect to internet in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: internet, dsl

I upgraded Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 but after upgrading I am not able to connect to internet. I want to tell you that I am trying to connect to internet through DSL cable. The error message it is displaying is

```
Connection activation failed
(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActivationConnection/4' failed in libnm-glib.
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the connection that doesn't work and recreating it? To do that, right click on the network icon -> Edit connections and select delete. Now press add and select Ethernet.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this several times but nothing is working

Comment: somebody help out here. i too face the same prob. losing my internet connectivity. have to restart to get the connectivity. then i lose it again after a few minutes

Comment: open your terminal and try executing these commands one by one: 1. sudo sudo ppoeconf and press enter  for yes on everything and give your username and password where required then execute the next command 2. sudo pon dsl-provider. this might solve your problem. And to close your connection type 3. sudo poff.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214

Comment: Still same error is pnping out.

Comment: Any other way to fix this.

Comment: Please somebody get me out of this problen. the internet connection is so important to me at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried rebooting, deleting and re-creating the connections, I tried purging and reinstalling the network manager, nothing worked for me...

Until! Another user suggested (re)installing pppoe:

```
sudo apt-get install pppoe
```

Worked like a charm :-)